# how to find the sum of an infinite HP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

While solving this ODE:-
${x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+.....}\over{1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}.......}$=$\frac{dy-dx}{dx+dy}$, I divided the numerator by the denominator.
I have searched around this site but can't seem to find any answer.

to arrive  at the HP
$$x(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}.....) =\frac{dy-dx}{dx+dy} $$, where the constants on the LHS are in HP
I have no idea how to add these terms, could someone please help?

Comment: You could write it shorter as $\frac{y'-1}{1+y'}=\frac{\cosh x}{\sinh x}$. This could lead to something like $y'=-e^{2x}$?

Comment: I'm not familair with hyperbolic trig functions, so I'm not trying that

Comment: But you are familiar with the exponential function, its power series and can identify its odd and even parts?

Comment: yes, E= equation

Comment: oh, my bad. Sorry

Comment: HP means what here ?

Comment: harmonic progression(at least $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5} $ are in HP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not cancel individual terms in a quotient of sums or series. One can do something slightly in this direction when computing continued-fraction expansions, but that is not relevant here.

Call the series in the numerator $S(x)$, the one in the denominator $C(x)$. Expand as exact equation and collect terms. Or solve for $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Use that $$C(x)\pm S(x)=e^{\pm x}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Why exactly can't I cancel out the terms?

Comment: Because you can only cancel common factors. If you divide a factor out in one term, you have to divide the same out in all terms of the sum or series.

Comment: I basically just divided the numerator and denominator by the denominator why is that wrog?

Comment: Yes, because you did it term-by-term. But you have a quotient of sums, not a sum of quotients. Distributive laws are like that.

Comment: oh yeah, my bad. Thank you!